# Which board to use for wireless communication of small packages?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, wireless

I was hoping to get your advice on what Arduino boards to look at for a project I'm working on. The project involves two separate boxes in different rooms of my apartment (~ 5-10 feet away from each other) and needs to allow wireless communication of very small amounts of information (think like 5 bytes). However, this transfer needs to be very rapid (within 200 milliseconds).

While I have worked a good bit with the Arduino Uno, I haven't worked with boards with Wifi capabilities.

The boards I know of are: Esp32, Esp8266, Arduino MKR 1010, Arduino Mega RobotDyn.

What would be the best board for a project like this / are there other boards that are well-suited for a project like this?

Thanks!

Comment: i would consider ESP-NOW. It's under-appreciated imho for what it can do, but it's taken my smart home to a new level with cheap battery-powered "infinite standby"  sensors and actuators.

Answer (score 1):

WiFi round trip time is about 2-50 ms (50 is the worst case), so, you can use the ESP's and the UDP/TCP.

On the other hand, you can use the NRF433 module, but in this case, you have to develop your own channel level protocol, with error detection/correction and so on.

Also, there are [ZigBee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigbee) module. They developed for home automation specially.